# java how can I unpack the list and add elements to datatable one by one?

Tags: java, datatable, datatables

Good afternoon to everyone!
Here is how my code looks like now: (I've shortened it)

I have a datatable to fill in and then use it for visualization on website written in Javascript

```
DataTable usd_table = DataTableBuilder
                .create("usd_final_sum")
                .withColumn(String.class,
                        "Line", new ArrayList<>())
                .withColumn(String.class,
                        "Date1", new ArrayList<>())
                .withColumn(String.class,
                        "Date2", new ArrayList<>())
                ... (95 rows more)
                .withColumn(String.class,
                        "Date97", new ArrayList<>())
                .build().get();
```

Then I fill it in:

```
        usd_table = usd_table.rows().addValues(cum_cash_list.get(0), 
cum_cash_list.get(1), 
    ....... (95 rows more), 
    cum_cash_list.get(98)).get();
```

There are 98 rows when creating and 98 rows when filling in.. Terrible..

So it works, but it is so long code. How can I shorten it?
cum_cash_list consists of String values

May be some List iterator or while loop, I don't know..

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop:

```
var builder = DataTableBuilder
                .create("usd_final_sum")
                .withColumn(String.class,
                        "Line", new ArrayList<>())
//Here numRows is 98 or however many rows you have
for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i ++) {
  builder = builder.withColumn(String.class, "Date" + i, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

At the end of the loop, builder will have the columns you need. Then you can say

```
DataTable usd_table = builder.build().get();
```

EDIT: To fill in the database, you can just use a for-loop again. I assume that the `addValues` method uses varargs, so you can pass in an array:

```
//I don't know the return type of cum_cash_list.get(int), so I'm naming it Value
Value[] values = new Value[98/*or number of rows*/];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) values[i] = cum_cash_list.get(i);
usd_table = usd_table.rows().addValues(values).get();
```

EDIT: That var isn't a JS var, I just wasn't sure whether the type of builder would be `DataTableBuilder` or something else.

Comment: what about filling in the datatable?) do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Chingiz Use a for-loop for that too. Check my edited answer